# Count online people in a dictionary and show the name of the person

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary of people's online statuses, and I am able to count the number of people who are online, but I want to show the names of the people who are online.

Example:

```
def online_count(people):
   return len([person for person in people if people[person] == "online"])
statuses = {
"Alice": "online",
"Bob": "offline",
"Eve": "online",
}
print(online_count(statuses))
```

How do I show the names of the people who are online?

Comment: Isn't that just the list you're already finding the length of?

Comment: ```return [a for a in people if people[a].lower()=="online"]``` for returning names

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
def online_names(people):
    return [name for name, status in people.items() if status == 'online']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `items()` to iterate over both the keys and values of the dictionary. Then you can return the keys when the value matches your criteria.

```
def online_people(people):
    return [person for person, status in people.items() if status == "online"]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a spurious list. You can also disregard keys completely for the count:

```
def online_count(people):
    return sum(v == "online" for v in people.values())
```

For the names, you can do:

```
def online_names(people):
    return [p for p in people if people[p] == "online"]

>>> online_count(statuses)
2
>>> online_names(statuses)
['Alice', 'Eve']
```